# Currently compiling, but receiving nothing but end to program?

Tags: java, methods, input

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class PD {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);    

        System.out.print("Enter your number: " ); 
        int number = input.nextInt();
        for (int count = 2; count < number; count++) {
            String blank = "";
            String Snumber = count + blank; 
            if (isPalindromic(count) && isPrime(count) && 
                isPalindromic((int)(Snumber.length())) && 
                isPrime((int)(Snumber.length()))){
                    System.out.println( count + "is double palidromic prime");
            }
            else
                continue; 
        }
    }

    // method to find palindromic 
    public static boolean isPalindromic(int count) {
        String blank = ""; 
        String convert = count + blank; 
        for (int i = 0, q = 1; i <= (convert.length()/2 - 1); i++, q++) { 
            if (convert.substring(i,q) == convert.substring(convert.length() - q, convert.length() - i)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false; 
    }

    // method to find prime
    public static boolean isPrime(int count ) {
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= count/2; divisor++) { 
            if (count % divisor == 0) { 
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Currently the thing compiles and ask for input, but it always results in nothing.

Does someone see something wrong with my program that is obvious wrong.

Overall, the program receives input and has to look through values 2 until it hits the value the user wants and print the ones that follow the if statement.

Comment: On StackOverflow, it's generally frowned upon to post blocks of code and ask others to find bugs in them for you. Can you please add what you've tried so far to locate the bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `isPalindromic` method is not functioning properly. It is not returning `true` for palindromic numbers. Change it to this:

```
public static boolean isPalindromic(int count) {
        String blank = "";
        String convert = count + blank;
        int n = convert.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < (n / 2 + 1); i++) {
            if (convert.charAt(i) != convert.charAt(n - i - 1)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
}
```